# How to crawl websites that have front end js framework

Tags: search, swiftype

We are currently trying swiftype and wanted to see how to Crawl our website that has javascript frameworks becauase there are async calls.

I created a engine and was able to run  a crawl based my sitemap, but instead of reading the actual content, it is reading my Angular js code.

For eg:

if have an angular code something like 
`<div ng-class='grey title'> {{ctrl.title}}</div>`

and if this data gets binded on page load, instead of reading the title, it reads the actual code as `{{ctrl.title}}`
so when i search, the page returns something like 
**"This article is about {{ctrl.title}} . We take you through.... "**

Any idea on how to make it compatible with js frameworks?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a "headless" browser through i.e. [Playwright.dev](https://playwright.dev/).  "Headless" means it doesn't have a GUI. Since it's actually a browser it'll interpret the page correctly. It can be started from a JavaScript that runs server-side. Check out [Web Scraping : Handling AJAX website part I](https://ksah.in/web-scraping-handling-ajax-website/) and the code on GitHub: [introWebScraping](https://github.com/ksahin/introWebScraping).